# In Google Chrome how to disable popup box that ask 'Phone to call with'

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, phone-call, tel

In Google Chrome when I click on an anchor "**a**" element with "**tel:**" in **href** it always open the popup to call with a phone. It make conflicts with an **extension** I want to use to **manage calls**!

Sometimes it fires the extension and sometimes it fires the chrome popup, it seems to be related on how the data comes loaded by the site (direct load by the page or asyncronus with ajax).

How to disable the default "**call with**" by Google Chrome ?